# how can produce json array with while in php

Tags: php, json

i want return my data from mysql to json array with do while loop.
when i return one record with json it is well. but i want return list of array in one json array.
how can do that with index in while? my code have error and i don't know how can do it. with one record it is well but more can't.

```
 $json="array(";
  do{
    $json=."'$row_query['id']'=>array('fname'=>$row_query['fname'],'lname'=>$row_query['lname']),";

 } while ($row_query = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query));
 json=.")";
echo json_encode($json,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: The do-while loop is incorrect - in the first iteration, there's no `$row_query`, as this var is set after the first iteration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's **no need** to add quotes, brackets, parentheses or whatever. `json_encode` function will do it for you. Just provide an **array** to it:

```
$json = [];
while ($row_query = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $json[$row_query['id']] = [
        'fname'=>$row_query['fname'],
        'lname'=>$row_query['lname'],
    ];
}
echo json_encode($json,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the most super easy version. You may try this.

```
$json = new array();
do{
array_push($json,$row_query);
} while ($row_query = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query));
```

**or**

```
$json = [];
do{
 $json[] = $row_query;
} while ($row_query = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query));
```

Atlast encode your json variable.

```
$json = json_encode($json);
echo $json;
```